# System.Net.Mail exposes hostname and ip address

Tags: .net, vb.net

When i send an email through one of the large providers ex: Google, yahoo, hotmail. the System.Net.Mail exposes my ip address and pc name in the headers ex: Received: from Andriy-PC (XXXX.comcastbusiness.net. [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX])

is there a way to remove it from the email?

here is my code:

```
            Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
            Dim mail As New MailMessage()
            SmtpServer.Credentials = New  _
            Net.NetworkCredential(email.account, email.pass)
            SmtpServer.Port = email.port
            SmtpServer.Host = email.smtp

            If email.ssl = 1 Then
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
            Else
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = False
            End If

            mail = New MailMessage()
            mail.From = New MailAddress(email.account)
            mail.To.Add(recipient)
            mail.Subject = user_subject
            mail.Body = body
            mail.Sender = New MailAddress(email.account)
            SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried setting the Send'er?

Comment: yes i have and it doesnt work:(

Comment: So - you want to anonymize the source of emails? That doesn't strike you as a potentially unfriendly behaviour, and something to be viewed with suspicion?

Comment: im ok with it saying my email or something like smtp.gmail.com, but the name of the host computer is a security risk in my opinion

Comment: Is Andriy-PC the name of your PC?  It almost looks like the MTA is getting the information from the connection.  If that is true then you can't do much about it that I know of.

Comment: Yes that is the name of my PC. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **No.** There is no way to remove it per the SMTP specs which require that properly conformant MTAs (Mail Transport Agents) add `received` headers as the message is relayed, building a 'chain of custody' list of `received` headers that allow one to trace how the mail traveled from sender to recipient.

See [RFC 5321](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5321) and [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5322) for details, in particular §4.4 of RFC 5321:

```
4.4.  Trace Information

   When an SMTP server receives a message for delivery or further
   processing, it MUST insert trace ("time stamp" or "Received")
   information at the beginning of the message content, as discussed in
   Section 4.1.1.4.

   This line MUST be structured as follows:

   o  The FROM clause, which MUST be supplied in an SMTP environment,
      SHOULD contain both (1) the name of the source host as presented
      in the EHLO command and (2) an address literal containing the IP
      address of the source, determined from the TCP connection.

   o  The ID clause MAY contain an "@" as suggested in RFC 822, but this
      is not required.

   o  If the FOR clause appears, it MUST contain exactly one <path>
      entry, even when multiple RCPT commands have been given.  Multiple
      <path>s raise some security issues and have been deprecated, see
      Section 7.2.

   An Internet mail program MUST NOT change or delete a Received: line
   that was previously added to the message header section.  SMTP
   servers MUST prepend Received lines to messages; they MUST NOT change
   the order of existing lines or insert Received lines in any other
   location.

   As the Internet grows, comparability of Received header fields is
   important for detecting problems, especially slow relays.  SMTP
   servers that create Received header fields SHOULD use explicit
   offsets in the dates (e.g., -0800), rather than time zone names of
   any type.  Local time (with an offset) SHOULD be used rather than UT
   when feasible.  This formulation allows slightly more information
   about local circumstances to be specified.  If UT is needed, the
   receiver need merely do some simple arithmetic to convert the values.
   Use of UT loses information about the time zone-location of the
   server.  If it is desired to supply a time zone name, it SHOULD be
   included in a comment.

   When the delivery SMTP server makes the "final delivery" of a
   message, it inserts a return-path line at the beginning of the mail
   data.  This use of return-path is required; mail systems MUST support
   it.  The return-path line preserves the information in the <reverse-
   path> from the MAIL command.  Here, final delivery means the message
   has left the SMTP environment.  Normally, this would mean it had been
   delivered to the destination user or an associated mail drop, but in
   some cases it may be further processed and transmitted by another
   mail system.

   It is possible for the mailbox in the return path to be different
   from the actual sender's mailbox, for example, if error responses are
   to be delivered to a special error handling mailbox rather than to
   the message sender.  When mailing lists are involved, this
   arrangement is common and useful as a means of directing errors to
   the list maintainer rather than the message originator.

   The text above implies that the final mail data will begin with a
   return path line, followed by one or more time stamp lines.  These
   lines will be followed by the rest of the mail data: first the
   balance of the mail header section and then the body (RFC 5322 [4]).

   It is sometimes difficult for an SMTP server to determine whether or
   not it is making final delivery since forwarding or other operations
   may occur after the message is accepted for delivery.  Consequently,
   any further (forwarding, gateway, or relay) systems MAY remove the
   return path and rebuild the MAIL command as needed to ensure that
   exactly one such line appears in a delivered message.

   A message-originating SMTP system SHOULD NOT send a message that
   already contains a Return-path header field.  SMTP servers performing
   a relay function MUST NOT inspect the message data, and especially
   not to the extent needed to determine if Return-path header fields
   are present.  SMTP servers making final delivery MAY remove Return-
   path header fields before adding their own.

   The primary purpose of the Return-path is to designate the address to
   which messages indicating non-delivery or other mail system failures
   are to be sent.  For this to be unambiguous, exactly one return path
   SHOULD be present when the message is delivered.  Systems using RFC
   822 syntax with non-SMTP transports SHOULD designate an unambiguous
   address, associated with the transport envelope, to which error
   reports (e.g., non-delivery messages) should be sent.

   Historical note: Text in RFC 822 that appears to contradict the use
   of the Return-path header field (or the envelope reverse-path address
   from the MAIL command) as the destination for error messages is not
   applicable on the Internet.  The reverse-path address (as copied into
   the Return-path) MUST be used as the target of any mail containing
   delivery error messages.

   In particular:
   o  a gateway from SMTP -> elsewhere SHOULD insert a return-path
      header field, unless it is known that the "elsewhere" transport
      also uses Internet domain addresses and maintains the envelope
      sender address separately.

   o  a gateway from elsewhere -> SMTP SHOULD delete any return-path
      header field present in the message, and either copy that
      information to the SMTP envelope or combine it with information
      present in the envelope of the other transport system to construct
      the reverse-path argument to the MAIL command in the SMTP
      envelope.

   The server must give special treatment to cases in which the
   processing following the end of mail data indication is only
   partially successful.  This could happen if, after accepting several
   recipients and the mail data, the SMTP server finds that the mail
   data could be successfully delivered to some, but not all, of the
   recipients.  In such cases, the response to the DATA command MUST be
   an OK reply.  However, the SMTP server MUST compose and send an
   "undeliverable mail" notification message to the originator of the
   message.

   A single notification listing all of the failed recipients or
   separate notification messages MUST be sent for each failed
   recipient.  For economy of processing by the sender, the former
   SHOULD be used when possible.  Note that the key difference between
   handling aliases (Section 3.9.1) and forwarding (this subsection) is
   the change to the backward-pointing address in this case.  All
   notification messages about undeliverable mail MUST be sent using the
   MAIL command (even if they result from processing the obsolete SEND,
   SOML, or SAML commands) and MUST use a null return path as discussed
   in Section 3.6.

   The time stamp line and the return path line are formally defined as
   follows (the definitions for "FWS" and "CFWS" appear in RFC 5322
   [4]):

   Return-path-line  = "Return-Path:" FWS Reverse-path <CRLF>

   Time-stamp-line  = "Received:" FWS Stamp <CRLF>

   Stamp          = From-domain By-domain Opt-info [CFWS] ";"
                  FWS date-time
                  ; where "date-time" is as defined in RFC 5322 [4]
                  ; but the "obs-" forms, especially two-digit
                  ; years, are prohibited in SMTP and MUST NOT be used.

   From-domain    = "FROM" FWS Extended-Domain

   By-domain      = CFWS "BY" FWS Extended-Domain

   Extended-Domain  = Domain /
                    ( Domain FWS "(" TCP-info ")" ) /
                    ( address-literal FWS "(" TCP-info ")" )

   TCP-info       = address-literal / ( Domain FWS address-literal )
                  ; Information derived by server from TCP connection
                  ; not client EHLO.

   Opt-info       = [Via] [With] [ID] [For]
                  [Additional-Registered-Clauses]

   Via            = CFWS "VIA" FWS Link

   With           = CFWS "WITH" FWS Protocol

   ID             = CFWS "ID" FWS ( Atom / msg-id )
                  ; msg-id is defined in RFC 5322 [4]

   For            = CFWS "FOR" FWS ( Path / Mailbox )

   Additional-Registered-Clauses  = CFWS Atom FWS String
                                  ; Additional standard clauses may be
                                  added in this
                                  ; location by future standards and
                                  registration with
                                  ; IANA.  SMTP servers SHOULD NOT use
                                  unregistered
                                  ; names.  See Section 8.

   Link           = "TCP" / Addtl-Link

   Addtl-Link     = Atom
                  ; Additional standard names for links are
                  ; registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers
                  ; Authority (IANA).  "Via" is primarily of value
                  ; with non-Internet transports.  SMTP servers
                  ; SHOULD NOT use unregistered names.

   Protocol       = "ESMTP" / "SMTP" / Attdl-Protocol

   Attdl-Protocol = Atom
                  ; Additional standard names for protocols are
                  ; registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers
                  ; Authority (IANA) in the "mail parameters"
                  ; registry [9].  SMTP servers SHOULD NOT
                  ; use unregistered names.
```

Comment: Thank You! but is there a way to remove the name at least and leave the ip?

Comment: @Andriy: No. You don't add the `received` headers. The MTA(s) relaying the message do. And what goes in the header is mandated by the RFCs (`The FROM clause, which MUST be supplied in an SMTP environment, SHOULD contain both (1) the name of the source host as presented in the EHLO command and (2) an address literal containing the IP address of the source, determined from the TCP connection.`). The only reason for wanting to break the chain of custody is if you're a spammer that doesn't want to be identified.